# Изучение  Lisp

Tags: lisp

Подскажите, где взять примеры программ (посложнее чем "Helloworld"), желательно с описанием. Потому как после прочтения нескольких книг  в голове винигрет. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сам я на CL не программирую, всё что пишу здесь: результат чтения и участия в срачах на ЛОРе.

Как я понял, [PCL](http://lisper.ru/pcl/) уже прочтён.

Обратите внимание на сайт [lisper.ru](http://lisper.ru). Он написан на CL с использованием [RESTAS](https://github.com/archimag/restas).

Кроме того есть несколько лисперов у которых есть свои проекты. Уверен, на их коде можно поучиться:

- [love5an](https://github.com/Lovesan)
- [dmitry_vk](https://github.com/dmitryvk) (автор [cl-gtk2](https://github.com/dmitryvk/cl-gtk2))
- [archimag](https://github.com/archimag) (автор RESTAS)

Есть ещё много активных лисперов, но я не нашёл их на гитхабе.

Ещё есть http://common-lisp.net/, но многие библиотеки там староваты.

Вообще довольно много лисперов обитает на ЛОРе, так что там вы можете найти дополнительное инфо.

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Emacs

Comment: Дык а почему именно Common Lisp? Для чистоты восприятия. Методика от П.Грэма (кстати, у него на сайте есть его крутая книга по языку - "on lisp") - изучение программирования проводить на Schema, а макросы - на cl.

Answer (score 0):

К слову о срачах на ЛОР-е. По их результатам создан неплохой faq https://www.linux.org.ru/wiki/en/lisp-lor-faq
где сказано о литературе и примерах.

Answer (score 0):

1. Гитхаб - рекомендую читать код на схеме, как наиболее каноничный:
   https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=language%3AScheme&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=Scheme  а также решить свою задачу на любом диалекте Lisp (даже если это транслятор Javascript вроде Sibilant), находя примеры по конкретным вопросам.
2. Использовать EMACS и StumpWM (оконный менеджер, настраивающийся на Common Lisp) - отличная ежедневная практика.